# IMAP Error: Login failed - Roundcube

Tags: imap, roundcube

I'm trying to login to Roundcube only the program won't let me.

[image: roundcube login]

I can login to the said account from the shell and mail is setup and working correctly on my server for user 'admin'. It's RC that is the problem. If I check my logs:

```
/usr/local/www/roundcube/logs/errors
```

they show:

```
[21-Sep-2013 17:19:02 +0100]: IMAP Error: Login failed for admin from ip.ip.ip.ip. Could not connect to ip.ip.ip.ip:143: 
Connection refused in /usr/local/www/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 
(POST /roundcube/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

which doesn't give me many clues really, just leads me to:

```
public function connect($host, $user, $pass, $port=143, $use_ssl=null) {}
```

from

```
rcube_imap.php
```

Stuff I've tried, editing:

```
/usr/local/www/roundcube/config/main.inc.php
```

with:

```
// IMAP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or null to use
// best server supported one)
//$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = LOGIN; 
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = null;

// Log IMAP conversation to <log_dir>/imap or to syslog
$rcmail_config['imap_debug'] = /var/log/imap;
```

With a failed login attempt

```
/var/log/imap
```

doesn't even get written to, leaving me no clues. I'm using dovecot and Sendmail on a FreeBSD box with full root access. It's not an incorrect username password combination for sure.

Several Googles on the string 'Roundcube: Connection to storage server failed' are fruitless.

EDIT:

I needed an entry in

```
/etc/rc.conf

dovecot_enable="YES"
```

Schoolboy error.

Comment: Have you solved the problem in the meantime? I have had the same error message today, but probably with newer Roundcube + PHP versions...

Comment: @SebastianS I had the same error on Debian 9 but also saying "AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed.". The solution was to set `auth_username_format = %n` in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`, it is explained here: https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=10917.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a letsencrypt certificate and resolve it by disabling peer authentication:

```
$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
    'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => true, 'verify_peer_name' => false),
    'tls' => array('verify_peer' => true, 'verify_peer_name' => false),
);
```

Afterwards you can set the connection string like this (starttls):

```
$config['default_host'] = 'tls://your-host.tld';
$config['default_port'] = '143';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'tls://your-host.tld';
$config['smtp_port'] = '25';
```

Or like this (ssl approach):

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://your-host.tld';
$config['default_port'] = '993';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://your-host.tld';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
```

Make sure you use the fully qualified hostname of the certificate in the connection string (like your-host.tld) and not an internal hostname (like localhost).

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: This helped me to resolve the error with IMAP only.

In order to fix the SMTP send error, I had to use tls instead of ssl instead:

$config['smtp_server'] = 'tls://your-host.tld';

This is the reason:

https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Configuration

To use Implicit TLS, enter the hostname with prefix ssl://. To use STARTTLS, use prefix tls://.

Answer (score 1):

Change the maildir to whatever your system uses.

Change Dovecot mail_location setting to

`mail_location = maildir:~/Mail`

Change Postfix home_mailbox setting to

`home_mailbox = Mail/`

Restart services and away you go
Taken from this [fedoraforum post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1550832&postcount=4)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem... what files you changed?

Comment: `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Answer (score 1):

If you run `fail2ban`, then `dovecot` might get banned following failed Roundcube login attempts. This has happened to me twice already...

First, check if this is indeed the case:

`sudo fail2ban-client status dovecot`

If you get an output similar to this:

```
Status for the jail: dovecot
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed: 8
|  `- File list:    /var/log/mail.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 2
   `- Banned IP list:   X.X.X.X
```

i.e. the `Currently banned` number is higher than 0, then `fail2ban` was a bit overeager and you have to "unban" `dovecot`.

Run the `fail2ban` client in interactive mode:

`sudo fail2ban-client -i`

and at the `fail2ban>` prompt enter the following:

`set dovecot unbanip X.X.X.X`

where `X.X.X.X` is the IP address of your Dovecot server.

Exit from the interactive client and run `sudo fail2ban-client status dovecot` again. The `Currently banned:` field now should have a value of 0. What's more important, RoundCube should work again :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your mail server.

Check your ports in your mail server and reset it (if necessary):

- Port 25 (and 587) must be open for SMTP
- Port 143 (and 993) must be open for IMAP
- Port 110 must be open for POP3

Also open those ports in your firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dovecot` should solve the problem.

If not restart dovecot

```
sudo service dovecot restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share this solution too, maybe in the future it could help someone.
Maybe we are using the wrong `CA cert` for `letsencrypt`, so to fix this issue, first of all find your correct location of `chain.pem` file, then edit the Roundcube's config file, in instance my config file was located in here: `/var/www/html/roundcube/config/config.inc.php`

then add these lines and save it.don't forget to put your domain in first line.

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://<your-domain>';

$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
 'ssl'         => array(
    'verify_peer'  => false,
    'verify_depth' => 3,
    'cafile'       => '/var/www/html/roundcube/config/chain.pem',
  ),
);
```

have a great day ...